# Postgres copy a tab file with quotes

Tags: postgresql

How to import a file in this format -

```
"ID"      "NBR"    

"101931126593"  "3"
```

I have tried the following -

1) `\copy last from 'test1.txt' with CSV DELIMITER E'\t';`

2) `\copy last from 'test1.txt' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;`

3) `\copy last from 'test1.txt';`

Below is the error I get -

`ERROR:  missing data for column "nbr"`

Comment: It doesn't appear to seperated by tabs? (your delimiter is set to `\t`)

Comment: It is separated by tab. @Mark

Comment: If that blank line between the header and the data is actually in the file, it will give that error.